# Is it possible to include a file outside Python package in wheel/bdist/sdist?

Tags: setup.py, python-packaging, python-wheel

I am the author of [KiKit](https://github.com/yaqwsx/KiKit). KiKit is a tool using [KiCAD](https://kicad-pcb.org/)'s Python API. KiKit also serves as a plugin for KiCAD. To register a plugin for KiCAD, you have to place a Python file in a specific location (e.g., `/usr/share/kicad/scripting/plugins/` or `~/.kicad_plugins/` - see [KiCAD doc](https://docs.kicad-pcb.org/doxygen/md_Documentation_development_pcbnew-plugins.html) for details).

I distribute KiKit as a python package via pip so my users can just type `pip install kikit` and not care about anything else. I would like to be able to register the plugin within the installation step so the users don't have to perform this step manually.

I know that wheel does not support arbitrary code execution thus no post-installation script is possible. But I wasn't able to find out if it is possible to include a file that will be installed on a location outside the root of the package. If so, how can I specify it in `setup.py`?

PS: I am aware of the option to provide an extra script, e.g., `register-kikit`, which would register the plugin. But I would like to include it in the installation step so there is a lesser chance of the user forgetting to do so.

Comment: You can look into `data_files` (in the docs for _setuptools_ and/or _distutils_), although I would definitely not recommend it. Actually, in you specific use case, it might not even work at all. -- You mention an additional script `kikit-register-kicad-plugin`, this is a much better idea. -- Something else you could experiment with as well (no guarantees): `pip install --target ~/.kicad_plugins/ kikit`.